# MySQL return single result for each unique column pair

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a table for user #129.  Messages are either TO or FROM him.

I would like the most RECENT messages that were sent/received by user (eg. 128, 130, 131.. etc.)

---

```
id msgTo msgFrom msgContent msgDate

1   129 130 Birmingham  2014-12-19 8:58
2   130 129 Montgomery  2014-12-19 10:59
3   129 131 Anchorage   2014-12-19 11:21
4   131 129 Phoenix 2014-12-19 11:24
5   131 129 Tucson  2014-12-19 11:32
6   128 129 Mesa    2014-12-19 11:34
7   129 128 Chandler    2014-12-19 11:36
8   129 131 Glendale    2014-12-19 11:47
9   131 129 Gilbert 2014-12-19 11:49
10  129 130 Scottsdale  2014-12-19 16:51
```

---

DESIRED RESULT --->

```
id  msgTo msgFrom msgContent msgDate

10  129 130 Scottsdale  2014-12-19 16:51
9   131 129 Gilbert 2014-12-19 11:49
7   129 128 Chandler    2014-12-19 11:36
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear.  You are asking for the most recent messages sent or received by a user, but your sample output contains _two_ records sent to user 129. Only one of them is the most recent.

Comment: This is user 129's table. Therefore he either sends or receives the message (which is why he is either in the msgTo or msgFrom column). First I want to sort by date, then find only one result per other user (eg. 130, 131, 128)

Comment: And you want to include _all_ other users in the output, if they are on the other side of the conversaion with 129, that is, the most recent interaction with each other user?  And ultimately, should there be only one interaction per other user, such that you don't show both the most recent message where 129 sent to 130 and the most recent where 129 received from 130?

Comment: 1) Yes include all. 2) Yes, one interaction only (regardless if sent or received). If 130 and 129 have a long list of messages going back and forth. I want the most recent message and it doesn't matter if it is sent or received by 129.

Comment: Any luck with this Michael?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE msgTo = 129 OR msgFrom = 129
ORDER BY msgDate DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this entire table is specific to user #129, then maybe restructuring the table is your best bet. Something like this:

```
TABLE USER_129_MESSAGES

id otherUser msgType msgContent  msgDate

1   130      from    Birmingham  2014-12-19 8:58
2   130      to      Montgomery  2014-12-19 10:59
3   131      from    Anchorage   2014-12-19 11:21
4   131      to      Phoenix     2014-12-19 11:24
5   131      to      Tucson      2014-12-19 11:32
6   128      to      Mesa        2014-12-19 11:34
7   128      from    Chandler    2014-12-19 11:36
8   131      from    Glendale    2014-12-19 11:47
9   131      to      Gilbert     2014-12-19 11:49
10  130      from    Scottsdale  2014-12-19 16:51
```

Then you can simply run:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_129_MESSAGES
GROUP BY otherUser
ORDER BY msgDate DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: That achieves the result, but I would have to restructure 1000's of tables. I'm sure this must be possible with a simple query.

Comment: When I use the above query, the GROUP BY orders the messages from each user by OLDEST first.  How could I make this return NEWEST first?  (I'm not talking about the "msgDate DESC" part. This is correct)

Answer (score 0):

You can order your result by msgDate field and set a result limit on the main query:

```
select * from [your_table]
where msgTo=[user id] or msgFrom=[user id]
order by msgDate desc
limit 3
```

Comment: This will return the first 3 rows of the table. I'm looking to filter so I have the most recent msg from each unique user.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE msgTo = 129 OR msgFrom = 129
```

---

If you also want order the row, You can some word, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE msgTo = 129 OR msgFrom = 129 ORDER BY id DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE msgTo = 129 OR msgFrom = 129 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have found the answer or not. While searching for the same problem I encountered this question and I have written a mysql query for this. Though I am  quite sure the query which I have written can further be optimized but it gives the desired results.

```
SELECT *
FROM message AS M
NATURAL JOIN
  (SELECT M2.msgFrom,
          M2.msgTo,
          max(M2.msgDate) AS msgDate
   FROM message AS M2
   GROUP BY M2.msgFrom,
            M2.msgTo ) AS N
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT *
 FROM (
         (SELECT *
          FROM
            (SELECT M3.msgFrom,
                    M3.msgTo,
                    max(M3.msgDate) AS msgDate
             FROM message AS M3
             WHERE M3.msgFrom = 129
             GROUP BY M3.msgFrom,
                      M3.msgTo) AS send
          WHERE EXISTS
              ( SELECT *
               FROM
                 (SELECT M4.msgFrom,
                         M4.msgTo,
                         max(M4.msgDate) AS msgDate
                  FROM message AS M4
                  WHERE M4.msgTo = 129
                  GROUP BY M4.msgFrom,
                           M4.msgTo) AS rec
               WHERE rec.msgDate > send.msgDate
                 AND rec.msgFrom = send.msgTo))
       UNION
         (SELECT *
          FROM
            (SELECT M5.msgFrom,
                    M5.msgTo,
                    max(M5.msgDate) AS msgDate
             FROM message AS M5
             WHERE M5.msgTo = 129
             GROUP BY M5.msgFrom,
                      M5.msgTo) AS rec1
          WHERE EXISTS
              (SELECT *
               FROM
                 (SELECT M6.msgFrom,
                         M6.msgTo,
                         max(M6.msgDate) AS msgDate
                  FROM message AS M6
                  WHERE M6.msgFrom = 129
                  GROUP BY M6.msgFrom,
                           M6.msgTo) AS send1
               WHERE send1.msgDate >= rec1.msgDate
                 AND send1.msgTo = rec1.msgFrom)) )AS Q
 WHERE M.msgFrom = Q.msgFrom
   AND M.msgTo = Q.msgTo
   AND M.msgDate = Q.msgDate)
ORDER BY msgDate DESC;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f04924/17)